Getting a 403 Forbidden from Steam WebApi even though I've used it before
A couple years ago I was really into studying API integrations so I would create a lot of projects just to mess around with developer APIs around the web (Twitter, Discord, etc). One of those APIs was Steam WebApi. So I did get a WebApi key through steam and I did manage to make it work.
Today, after a long time I thought about making a website for a small group of friends, we play Counter Strike pretty often and have a set up a nice discord server and I wanted to make a bot that would occasionally get info of the players we have in the group.
Problem is... I can't get Steam WebApi to work anymore... I revoked the previous key I had a long time ago and made a new one so that I could start coding and it doesn't matter what I do, I keep getting FORBIDDEN 403 whenever I try to make a request to any Steam WebApi endpoint.

"Forbidden    Access is denied. Retrying will not help. Please verify your
key= parameter."

I tried revoking and requesting new API Keys a couple times under different domain names but still no dice...
I'm pretty sure I'm doing it right in Postman, I wonder if anybody else went through this when trying to use steam WebApi...
The URL I'm using for testing is as follows:
https://partner.steam-api.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v1/?steamid=<RANDOM_PROFILE_ID>&key=<MY_KEY>
(Hid the key and the profileId for obvious reasons)
I tried new Keys under different domain names, different endpoints (since some of them are for game publishers only) and also tried inserting the key under a header instead of typing it in the URL (as mentioned in the steamworks documentation).
All of those result in the same FORBIDDEN 403.

You are requesting data for YOUR account -- i.e. the one that the WebAPI key actually belongs to, right? These keys only allow software to access to your account, not accounts from other people.
